# How to create multiple submit link buttons?

Tags: html

I have two vertical framesets, the left frame will show the links, and the right frame will show the contents when a link is clicked. Right now, what I have is when I click a link, the content is opened in a new tab. I know that to change this we have to change target. I have done so but nothing changed. Can someone help to resolve this problem? Thank you. Here is my code for the part.

```
<form method="link" action="stock.xml" target="logo.html">
  <input id="company.xsl" name="file" type="submit" value="Browse by Company" ><br></br>
  <input id="category.xsl" name="file" type="submit" value="Browse by Category" ><br></br>
  <input id="sale.xsl" name="file" type="submit" value="Browse by Sale">
</form>
```

Also, I have 3 xsl files and 1 xml file. Is there any way to link all xsl files to the xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, method should be get or post, the action should be the file that is going to handle the form action, and target should be the name of the from you want it to submit to.  see here http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2069/set-the-target-frame-of-a-form/